# How to create a relation between two modules using EntityFramework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I need to build a relation between two tables without using the primary key property.

Here are my entity models

```
public class RealEstateProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    //... List of all properties

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PostalCode))]
    public virtual RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriority PostalCodePriority { get; set; }
}

public class RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriority
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // This is a unique property on the database
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public int? Sort { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PostalCode)), InverseProperty(nameof(RealEstateProperty.PostalCodePriority))]
    public ICollection<RealEstateProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

The above relations throw the following exception

```
InvalidOperationException: The relationship from 'RealEstateProperty.PostalCodePriority' to 'RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriority.Properties' with foreign key properties {'PostalCode' : string} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.
```

The end result will need to look something like this

```
SELECT p.Id, p.PostalCode, z.Sort
FROM RealEstateProperties AS p
LEFT JOIN RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriorities AS z ON z.PostalCode = p.PostalCode
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the entire line `[ForeignKey(nameof(PostalCode)), InverseProperty(nameof(RealEstateProperty.PostalCodePriority))]`? That line doesn't make a lot of sense to me and the exception tells you there's something that doesn't make sense

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that throw a different exception `InvalidOperationException: The relationship from 'RealEstateProperty.PostalCodePriority' to 'RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriority.Properties' with foreign key properties {'PostalCode' : string} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.`

Comment: I think you will have to do this with the Fluent API. I don't have VS right now, but it should be along the lines of `model.Entity<RealEstateProperty>().HasOne(e => e.PostalCodePriority).WithMany(e => e.Properties).HasKey(e => e.PostalCode )` plus another call for the `RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriority.PostalCode` part (cannot remember the method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be used as principal end of a relationship, the non PK property `PostalCode` of the `RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriority` must be configured as [alternate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys). Then the relationship must be configured to use the alternate key rather than the primary key.

Both require fluent API (`HasAlternateKey`, `HasPrincipalKey`), so remove the `ForeignKey` and `InverveProperty` annotations (they are confusing anyway):

```
public class RealEstateProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    //... List of all properties

    //[ForeignKey(nameof(PostalCode))] <-- remove this...
    public virtual RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriority PostalCodePriority { get; set; }
}

public class RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriority
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // This is a unique property on the database
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public int? Sort { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey(nameof(PostalCode)), InverseProperty(nameof(RealEstateProperty.PostalCodePriority))] // <-- ... and this
    public ICollection<RealEstateProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

and use the following fluent configuration instead:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RealEstatePropertyPostalCodePriority>()
    .HasMany(pcp => pcp.Properties)
    .WithOne(p => p.PostalCodePriority)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.PostalCode)
    .HasPrincipalKey(pcp => pcp.PostalCode);
```